# Not able to download a file with % even after url encode

Tags: javascript, urlencode, url-encoding

I saved a file , which contains `% and %20`

when i click on a link,which is pointing to this file. By using javascript am doing `encodeURI(filePath)`.

Getting file not found error, but file is available.

Browser Chrome and IE, Server: IIS Server

actual URl : `http://<servername>/<Folder>/PDF/!%2-!@crackerunit&%_20151029203000_0.pdf`

encodedURl : `http://<servername>/<Folder>/PDF/!%252-!@crackerunit&%25_20151029203000_0.pdf`

Comment: have you tried using encodeURIComponent() instead? refer to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent

Comment: I do not have any query string values , so am using `encodeURI()`

Comment: Please show the actual code.

Comment: What server are you using?  Which browser?  Can you post the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

```
 1. Original pdf: !%2-!@crackerunit&%_20151029203000_0.pdf
 Use JavaScript encodeURI: encodeURI("!%2-!@crackerunit&%_20151029203000_0") 
 Resulting output: !%252-!@crackerunit&%25_20151029203000_0.pdf
 Complete url: http://<servername>/<Folder>/PDF/!%252-!@crackerunit&%25_20151029203000_0.pdf
 Once this url is accessed, you receive an exception: A potentially
 dangerous Request. Path  
 value was detected from the client (%). Solve this problem by following  
 step2 

 2. web.config changes:
 <system.web>
   <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" 
   />
 </system.web>
```

Comment: But escape has been depreciated.